# Button onClickListener not working in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Am trying to do some simple calculations,I set a Listener on my fragment But it doesn't trigger the `onClick` method and the log shows nothing,According to an accepted answer here this should work,and most of alternatives didn't work for me,What is the cause of this behavior This is my fragment

```
public class AttendanceFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    EditText ET_days,ET_week;
    TextView TV_attendance;
    Button btn;
    static int attendance;
    public static final String TAG = "Checking";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.attendance,container,false);

        ET_days= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.et_days);
        ET_week= (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.et_week);
        TV_attendance=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_attendance);
        btn=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btn_attendance);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);



        return v;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int days =Integer.parseInt(ET_days.getText().toString());
        int week= Integer.parseInt(ET_week.getText().toString());
        int d = days * 5;
        int w = week * 75;

        attendance= (d/w) * 100;
        String att= String.valueOf(attendance);
        Log.d("ATtendance",att);

        TV_attendance.setText("Your Current Attendance is:"+att);
    }

}
```

This my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_days"
        android:text="Enter The number of days you have missed so Far"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
    <EditText
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:hint="days missed"
    android:id="@+id/et_days"
    />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_week"
        android:text="Enter The Current school week Number "
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:hint="week number"
        android:id="@+id/et_week"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your Current Attendance is: 85%"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:id="@+id/tv_attendance"
        />

    <Button
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"

        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn_attendance"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Check Attendance"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:textColor="@color/white"


        />


</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT:
the fragment is part of 5 fragents in `BottomBar`,these are in my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 7;
    BottomBar mBottomBar;
   public static  int m= 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




        mBottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this,savedInstanceState);
        mBottomBar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.menu_main,new OnMenuTabClickListener()



        {


            public void onMenuTabSelected(@IdRes int i) {
                if(i==R.id.Bottombaritemone)
                {
                    NewsFRagment f = new NewsFRagment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_container,f).commit();

                }
                else if(i==R.id.Bottombaritemtwo)
                {
                   AttendanceFragment f =new AttendanceFragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_container,f).commit();
                }
                else if(i==R.id.Bottombaritemthree)
                {
                    PhoneFragment f =new PhoneFragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_container,f).commit();

                }
                else if(i==R.id.Bottombaritemfour)
                {

                    UploadFragment f =new UploadFragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_container,f).commit();
                    if (m == 0) {


                        if (isReadStorageAllowed()) {
                            //If permission is already having then showing the toast
                            //Existing the method with return
                            return;
                        }

                        //If the app has not the permission then asking for the permission
                        requestStoragePermission();
                    }

                }
                else if(i==R.id.Bottombaritemfive)
                {
                    FavoritesFragment f =new FavoritesFragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_container,f).commit();
                }
            }



            @Override
            public void onMenuTabReSelected(@IdRes int i) {

            }
        });
        mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(0, "#F44336");
        mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(1,"#9C27B0");
        mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(2,"#03A9F4");
        mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(3,"#795548");
        mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(4,"#FF6F00");

        BottomBarBadge unread;
        unread = mBottomBar.makeBadgeForTabAt(3,"#FF0000",13);
        unread.show();


    }


    //We are calling this method to check the permission status
    private boolean isReadStorageAllowed() {
        //Getting the permission status
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        //If permission is granted returning true
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            return true;

        //If permission is not granted returning false
        return false;
    }

    //Requesting permission
    private void requestStoragePermission(){

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
            //If the user has denied the permission previously your code will come to this block
            //Here you can explain why you need this permission
            //Explain here why you need this permission
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Need permission to read fles for upload",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        //And finally ask for the permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
        Log.d("Permission Requested","Permission requested");
    }

    //This method will be called when the user will tap on allow or deny
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        //Checking the request code of our request
        if(requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE){

            //If permission is granted
            if(grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                //Displaying a toast
                Toast.makeText(this,"Permission granted now you can read the storage",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                //Displaying another toast if permission is not granted
                Toast.makeText(this,"Oops you just denied the permission",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: but you don't call onClick in tag <Button>

Comment: its necessary despite listener?? sorry am a beginner,so which method do i put in onClick tag in xml

Comment: Have you placed a breakpoint inside onClick to verify it's never called?. Also regarding the other comments, you don't need to add onClick in XML, adding purely in code is sufficient and just another way of doing it..

Comment: Am logging inside onClick,the Log doesent appear in Logcat

Comment: How is this fragment positioned compared to the activity or other fragments. Do you perhaps have another fragment or view that's overlapping the button preventing it from being clicked?

Comment: Dont really understand what you mean,But the fragment is part of a bottom bar which contains 4 other fragments,so this fragment pops up when i click a tab on BottonBar,shoud i post MainActivity?

Comment: why not just call button.setOnClickListener(<new listener>)?

Comment: i did but it didnt work so i changed,perhaps i should foucus on trying on that end

Comment: So i call it in xml nw and i get illegalStateExcwption error: cant find method in parentor ancester context

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
     switch (view.getId()){

     case R.id.R.id.btn_attendance:
 int days =Integer.parseInt(ET_days.getText().toString());
 int week= Integer.parseInt(ET_week.getText().toString());
 int d = days * 5;
 int w = week * 75;
 attendance= (d/w) * 100;
 String att= String.valueOf(attendance);
 Log.d("ATtendance",att);
 TV_attendance.setText("Your Current Attendance is:"+att);
 break;
 }
}
```

Now it should work as you want

Comment: Still nothing,nothing in Logcat,this is a real headache

Comment: try to clean and rebuild project.Just for a try

Comment: Still no luck,am using build tools 24.0.0 if that helps at all